# Sampling without replacement from a population with known fractions of duplicates, triplicates, etc.

Tags: probability, sampling

Suppose I have a population of a known size. For this population, p_1 + p_2 + .... + p_n = 1, where p_1 is the fraction of the population that has no duplicates, p_2 is the fraction of the population with one duplicate, and so on. p_1, p_2, and so on are all known values (and if it matters for approximate calculations, the fractions very quickly decrease in value, with anything above p_5 being negligible).

I take a random sample X (no replacement) from this population, where X << the total population size, and I want to find the expected fraction of X that will not be a unique item.

How do I proceed? Please forgive any confusing language above, I am attempting to translate a question into a math problem with no background in statistics.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the expected fraction that will not be a unique item".  Do you mean that the item will be duplicated in the sample, or that it will be duplicated in the sample?

Comment: commenter @saulspatz is probably meaning to point out that the are unique items in the population.

Comment: I believe this would be an example of the kind of set she's referring to. Suppose the population is x y z t t m m m n n n.  Then p_1 = 3/11 since only x, y, and z are unique. p_2 = 2/11, since t has exactly one duplicate. Finally, p_3 = 6/11 since m and n each have 2 duplicates.

Comment: It looks like you're expected to use some approximation method since they use the language X<<N. If it's from a textbook or lecture, can you tell us some of the approximation methods you've learned in the context of this problem?

Comment: Essentially in the final population X, I want to find a new p_1, let’s call it p_1’.

Comment: The note that X<<N is just a side note, in case there are approximations that can be used. This is not a textbook problem, so I can’t give you any context unfortunately. It is a problem I tried to put into “math terms” from a biological application.